# How to add your own picture on html?

Tags: html, css, image

How would you proceed to add a picture to a website (in html or css) from your own computer?

I know how to add a picture using a url but what if the picture is stored in a folder on my computer and not on the internet?

Comment: give the location of that image file ex- c:/documents/img.jpg

Comment: Would that work? I don't think so. That would be a security risk. That way you could trick an image into loading any file from the hard drive, and then you could get the raw image data using JavaScript and post it..

Comment: You can never make it happen

Comment: Upload it to the website?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="path/to/image/image.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to give the location of the image, use as reference the .html location.

Exs.:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

if your image is in the same folder of your html file.

```
<img src="../image.png">
```

if your image is outside of folder where your html file is and so on.

When you do that, you are going to be the only one able to access your page. If you want other people to see it you should be stored in a public folder in your web server. Look for [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) if you are a windows user.

Answer (score -1):

If the website is hosted on your computer then you can use your images stored on your computer.You can use `<img>` html tag to display image.

Otherwise if it is on some remote server, then you will need a static ip and a server on your computer to host images to remote server. It is not possible to have have server on remote internet location and images on local.

If website is on internet then copy the image to server and provide path.

Answer (score -1):

You can using the `img` tag to do this
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/dh55b4rz/ 
PS: I'm the creator of Codepenimg

Answer (score -1):

Let’s pretend we have an image of a car on our computer saved as “funny-dog.jpg” and we want to insert it into a webpage; this is the code we would use:

```
<img src="funny-dog.jpg">
```

Let’s analyze this code. First,  is the code for creating an image element. Next, the letters “src” are used as an attribute and stand for “source”. Basically, we need to provide the web browser with a value to the source of the image. Naturally, the value for the source attribute is “funny-dog.jpg”. This example assumes your image file is located in the same directory as your HTML file. If, for example, you had your image file inside a folder named “images” your code would look like this:

```
<img src="images/funny-dog.jpg">
```

There is one additional bit of code we must add before we are finished. We must assign an “alt” attribute and value to our image. The “alt” attribute stands for “alternative” and is used to provide a text-based alternative for viewers incase the image will not load, or if they are visually impaired. Here is what our code will look like:

```
<img src="funny-dog.jpg" alt="A funny dog sitting on the grass.">
```